# Tesseract OCR not working for java web application

Tags: java, tesseract, jsf-2.2, tess4j

I am trying to develop Java web Tesseract OCR application. Following code works perfectly :

```
public class App {

public String getImgText(String imageLocation) {
    ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
    instance.setDatapath(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("tessdata").getPath());
    System.out.println("Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(\"tessdata\").getPath() : "+Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("tessdata").getPath());
    instance.setLanguage("eng");

    try {
        String imgText = instance.doOCR(new File(imageLocation));
        return imgText;
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return "Error while reading image";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    App app = new App();
    System.out.println(app.getImgText("/home/user/Desktop/1.png"));
}
}
```

But when I trying to use the above code in my Java web(JSF) application after the line

```
  ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
```

nothing is printed out. Below is the code of my web application :

```
public String uploadImage(FileUploadEvent event) {
    System.out.println("webcore bean");
    //get uploaded file from the event
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = (UploadedFile) event.getFile();
    //create an InputStream from the uploaded file
    InputStream inputStr = null;
    try {
        inputStr = uploadedFile.getInputstream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //log error
    }

    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String directory = externalContext.getInitParameter("uploadDirectory");
    String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getFileName());

    File destFile = new File(directory, "static" + getFileExtension(filename));

    //use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils to copy the File
    try {
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStr, destFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //log error
    }
    System.out.println("getImageText(directory) : " + getImageText(directory));
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    return null;
}

private String getImageText(String imageLocation) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Before ");
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract1();
        System.out.println("After ");
        //instance.setDatapath("/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata");
        instance.setDatapath(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("tessdata").getPath());
        instance.setLanguage("eng");

        try {
            String imgText = instance.doOCR(new File(imageLocation));
            return imgText;
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            e.getMessage();
            return "Error while reading image";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Before returning null");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

The log "Before" is being printed but the log "After" is not being printed. I am using following technologies :

a) Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit OS

b) Netbeans

c) Maven

d) Glassfish 4.1

Comment: Have you [installed](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/tesseract-ocr-installation-and-usage-on-ubuntu-16-04/) tesseract correctly? What server do you use?

Comment: sure there not any exceptions or even a throwable?

Comment: Yes I have installed tesseract correclty and it works for console application. I use glassfish server 4.1 .

Comment: Yes I am sure there is no any exceptions and throwable.

Comment: That is impossible... unless... you are not runnimg the code you think you are running. And how is this jsf related btw. The `getImageText` is called so it jsf has done its job

Comment: Try `setDatapath` to Tesseract's `tessdata` folder, not to an embedded resource.

Comment: nguyenq, setDatapath is set to Tesseract's tessdata folder which is inside resources in other resources in netbeans where there is eng.traineddata file and it perfectly works for console application.

Comment: `} catch (TesseractException e) {            e.getMessage();` you're throwing away the most valuable info here. `e.getMessage()` does nothing. At least log the exceptions. There probably IS an exception, you just don't see it because of these bad catch-alls. (Catching everything just to log is not proper exception handling most of the time either. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23796357/1341535 for starters.)

Comment: I replaced "TesseractException e" with "Exception e" and got the result same as before.